# How can I duplicate an object and use different values?

Tags: javascript, object, clone

Is there a way I can duplicate a Object in JavaScript but then have different values in the duplicate?

For example if the original Object is as follows:

```
    a           = [];
    a[0]        = {};
    a[0].milk   = "Malted";
    a[1]        = {};
    a[1].milk   = "Goats";
```

I then want to copy the Object

```
    b = a;
    b[0].milk = "Semi";
```

If I use clone() or assign the previous 'a' Object is also altered so if I wrote

```
document.write(a[0].milk+" * "+b[0].milk);
```

The output is:

**Semi * Semi** where I am expecting **Malted, Semi**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `b = a` doesn't copy the object.

Comment: "*If I use clone()*" - what is `clone`?

Comment: apologies, I was mixing up JQuery / Javascript